# How can AC source with different voltage provide same power?

Tags: electricity, everyday-life, voltage, power

As some of us maybe aware, USA mains connection is 110 V while those in Asian countries are 220 V. How is it still possible for the Adapter to provide the necessary power to the device, say a laptop, despite having a lower voltage of 110 V at some places.

I understand that the Adapter is built to handle different input AC voltage, but is a 110 V source sufficient to provide the necessary power which a 220 V can.

Perhaps, it doesn't matter for light power consumers such as laptop, but won't High Power demanding home appliances such as Iron, may lack necessary input voltage to operate at maximum level.

Comment: Power = Voltage × Current

Comment: I took almost to the end of the 20th century, but the U.S.A. finally has standardized on 120V for residential power outlets.  We used to have 110V in some places, 117V in some places, even 125V I think.  But not any more.  It's all 120V now.

Answer (score 1):

I think that most people in the world knows that usa has app. 110 V while most(not just asia) of the rest of the world has app. 220 V. see map here http://users.telenet.be/worldstandards/electricity.htm

I believe that your question is asked with a limited back ground knowledge in electricity - and I will try to answer. Please correct me if you really want a technical explanation of how an adapter works.

It takes two things to deliver power to an apparatus - `voltage and current`. If you think of electricity like a flow of electrons, a river if you will. The `voltage` will tell you how much pressure there is on the electricity. -and the `current` tells you how much it is flowing. An adaptor that is build for more than one voltage will automatically adjust the current to deliver the same power. - If the pressure(voltage) drops, the flow(current) will increase.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually my background in electricity isn't that limited and I also don't want to know the technical explanation of how adapters work. I was just wondering, if having a lower source voltage would limit the net power output an adapter could provide. Say instead of 110 V, if the Mains line was just 5 V, would it be possible to design an adapter to provide power to existing laptops.

Comment: I believe that it is possible to design high power apparatus and electronics to low voltage supply. One example of this is large non superconducting magnets in physics experiments. Often the cables are finger thick hollow copper with cooling water inside, and the current is controlled by huge racks of many coupled transistors. - It would be a bit stupid to have a house size transformer to power a laptop :o)

Comment: Thanks for the information. I guess we can draw the necessary power, but as you mentioned the hardware design would have to change(house size transformer), so it does matter to some extent after all.

Answer (score 1):

In U.S.A., we have *two* different voltages available in any residence.  Residential power is 240V from a center-tapped transformer, giving two 120V "legs".  Most of the convenience outlets in a residence will be 120V with a maximum capacity of either 15A or 20A, and you won't find small appliances that pull any more than 1500W (12.5A).

You can find a few window air conditioners that require a 120V/20A outlet, but the majority of smaller ones plug into a 120V/15A outlet and most of the rest plug into a 240V outlet.

Our electric cookers typically plug in to a 240V/50A outlet, and our electric clothes dryers plug in to 240V/30A.  Other stationary equipment (e.g., whole-house HVAC systems, and electric water heaters) typically forego the plug, and are hard-wired to 240V.

---

Commercial power is a whole other story.  Office buildings and light industrial buildings that are supplied with three-phase power typically will use 277V, single-phase for the overhead lighting, and 480V, three-phase for HVAC, for elevators, and for other stationary machinery.

Heavy industrial buildings may be supplied with other, higher voltages.

---

> won't High Power demanding home appliances such as Iron, may lack necessary input voltage to operate at maximum level?

A clothes iron set to scorch-all-fabrics-quicker-than-you-can-blink uses about a thousand watts.  Our small appliance outlets can handle that.

The performance of portable heaters and electric kettles sold in the U.S.A. however may not be quite up to your expectations if you're from anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

For the most simple electrical devices such as an incandescent lightbulb or a water kettle, which are little more and a resistance, they will draw a quarter as much power if the voltage is halved, since $V^2/R$.

This will probably mean that their operation is unsatisfactory: much dimmer or much slower to heat up.  Things are slightly more complicated for an iron which is typically regulated using a thermostat.

This is why suppliers rate their appliances. The reverse of doubling the voltage can be dangerous as the power may be four times than the equipment is designed to take. 
You should either use equipment designed and labelled for the local voltage or use a transformer.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of using transformer to adjust voltage. However, a laptop power adapter can be connected to the entire range of 110-240. How are they able to provide the necessary power to the laptop with different input voltage? Does the adapter act as a DC Source, which is able to draw the necessary power from Mains irrespective of input voltage?

Comment: @shamim: I would guess that laptop PSUs using a switched mode power supply or possibly a linear regulator. These can cope with different input voltages and still produce the same output voltage. Wikipedia has good descriptions of both types of power supply.

Answer (score 0):

It depends greatly on what you are using. A 15 Amp circuit in Asia, running at a full 15 Amps through some appliance is using 3300 watts, while in the US is using half of that. So, high-power appliances (toasters, microwaves) can't simply be plugged in to the wrong voltage.

That said, most small appliances do not draw the entire 15 amps that a circuit can handle. A DC power adapter, in particular (like for a laptop or cellphone) is converting higher voltage (and current) AC to low voltage and low current DC. For example, my cellphone charger outputs 5V at 0.7A which corresponds to 3.5 watts, well under the the maximum power a circuit can provide. So, even the 1650W available in 110V-land is more than enough to power the adapter.